# What is the best way to maintain relevance of figures?

Tags: php, mysql, database

We have 2 tables - `Orders` and `Payment_Methods`.

`Orders` have `payment_method_id` column where we have foreign key for `Payment_Methods` table. At all we have 2 payment methods (cash / online payment).

Every 4 hours we have money collection from the cash inbox.
In our business it is very important to have exact current cash inbox figures.

Here are 2 ways of building current state of cash inbox.

1) Set up a table / field in database where we will have current cash inbox value. We will change it with each order saving. But it is hard to say how many checks we should do because payment statuses and payment methods in any order could be changed.

2) We should every time sum all order totals (`total` column) and minus all collections.

I know that I've written this in a very primitive way but I hope that I've managed to describe you the main problem.